# Huge response time of initial API calls in dropwizard web app

Tags: java, jetty, dropwizard, embedded-jetty

I have a simple dropwizard web app which exposes some REST apis. Everything works fine except in production environment, whenever we restart(for redeployment) the application then the **first few api takes a lot of time to respond** than the usual. Usually apis take somewhere between 10-500 ms of time to respond but after start up they suddenly takes from **20 seconds to 1.2 mins** for first couple of apis.

I tried adding verbose logging to measure time taken by each api but nothing in the logs seems to take more than a few milliseconds. It seems like issue is somewhere in the framework or in Jetty's http configuration.

Below is my connection's yaml configuration.

```yaml
server:
  applicationConnectors:
    - type: http
      port: 9179
      outputBufferSize: 32KiB
      idleTimeout: 30 seconds
      minBufferPoolSize: 64 bytes
      bufferPoolIncrement: 1KiB
      maxBufferPoolSize: 64KiB
      acceptorThreads: 1
      selectorThreads: 2
      acceptQueueSize: 1024
      reuseAddress: true
      soLingerTime: 600s
```

Main class

```java
class MyApplication extends Application<MyConfiguration> {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MyApplication().run(args)
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(Bootstrap<MyConfiguration> bootstrap) {
       //...
    }

    @Override
    public void run(MyConfiguration configuration, Environment environment)
            throws Exception {
        //...
    }
}
```

after a couple of mins all apis seems to work fine and problem seems to occur for the initial couple of minutes where latency of api becomes very high.
Can someone suggest some insights on understanding where this issue is occurring and how can it be resolved?

- Java Version in Use: **1.8**
- Drop-wizard version in Use: **0.9.2**
- Embedded Jetty version: **9.2.13**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Using SSL/TLS on HTTPS?

Comment: No, Not using HTTPS.

Comment: Can you upgrade?  You are 2 major versions behind on the 9.x series, and are using an [EOL (End of Life) release](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/download.php#version-table) of Jetty.  (Reminder: Jetty versioning since 1995 is `<servlet_support>.<major_version>.<minor_version>`) - 9.4.44 is the current version on 9.x.